# The called constructor method for WP_Widget in GFWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

Tags: plugins, php, widgets

```
The called constructor method for WP_Widget in GFWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()
```

Hi,

I have been getting some internal server errors on [a site I am making](http://staging-triteamglos.transitiongraphics.co.uk).  So I turned debug on and the above is the error I am receiving.

I do not seem to able to find a solid solution for this error, can anyone help please

Answer (score 2):

You are using a deprecated way to declare widgets. WordPress is anticipating on `constructor` being deprecated in PHP 7.0, [in favour of `__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). Please refer to the [Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to see how widgets are constructed these days.

If the GFWidget you mention is generated by a plugin that plugin is very much outdated and probably shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Slightly odd, the two plugins are gravity forms and yoast. Both are up-to-date. Just seems a little odd that such well developed plugins are using updated methods

Comment: Even more strange: the source at github says the widget is [already using `__construct`](https://github.com/UsabilityDynamics/wp-gravityforms/blob/master/widget.php) Perhaps your install got corrupted one way or the other.